# Powershell: Filter Hashtable - and get back a Hastable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Filtering a Hashtable using GetEnumerator always returns a object[] instead of a Hashtable:

```
# Init Hashtable
$items = @{ a1 = 1; a2 = 2; b1 = 3; b2 = 4}
# apply a filter
$filtered = $items.GetEnumerator() | ?{ $_.Key -match "a.*" }
# The result looks great
$filtered
  Name                           Value
  ----                           -----
  a2                             2
  a1                             1
# … but it is not a Hashtable :-(
$filtered.GetType()
  IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
  -------- -------- ----                                     --------
  True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Is there a nice solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot for any Help!,
kind regards, 
Tom

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$filtered` is an array of dictionary entries. There's no single cast or ctor for this as far as I know.

You can construct a hash though:

```
$hash = @{}
$filtered | ForEach-Object { $hash.Add($_.Key, $_.Value) }
```

Another workflow:

```
# Init Hashtable
$items = @{ a1 = 1; a2 = 2; b1 = 3; b2 = 4}

# Copy keys to an array to avoid enumerating them directly on the hashtable
$keys = @($items.Keys)
# Remove elements not matching the expected pattern
$keys | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -notmatch "a.*") {
        $items.Remove($_)
    }
}

# $items is filtered
```

Comment: Hi briantist, thank you **very much** for your fast & complete answer! I could not believe that there is no single cast or ctor for this, but you're probably right. At least, the workaround is transparent & usable :-)

Comment: You probably want to replace `$items.Keys` with `@($items.Keys)` to not enumerate collection while you remove items from it.

Comment: You need to use `@()` or `$()`. Plain parenthesis will not fix the problem.

Comment: @PetSerAl or I can be a little clearer and just use a separate variable :-p

Comment: You still need to use `$keys = @($items.Keys)` or `@($keys) | ForEach-Object ...`. You need to make a copy of collection before you start enumerating it. Assigning to variable do not make that copy.

Comment: @PetSerAl you're absolutely correct; my brain is not working today.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an even simpler function, it even has include and exclude functionality

```
function Select-HashTable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)][Hashtable]$Hashtable,
        [String[]]$Include = ($HashTable.Keys),
        [String[]]$Exclude
    )

    if (-not $Include) {$Include = $HashTable.Keys}

    $filteredHashTable = @{}
    $HashTable.keys.where{
        $PSItem -in $Include
    }.where{
        $PSItem -notin $Exclude
    }.foreach{
        $filteredHashTable[$PSItem] = $HashTable[$PSItem]
    }
    return $FilteredHashTable
}
```

Examples:

`$testHashtable = @{a=1;b=2;c=3;d=4}`

```
$testHashTable | Select-HashTable -Include a

Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              1
```

```bsh
$testHashTable | Select-HashTable -Exclude b
Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              3
d                              4
a                              1
```

```
$testHashTable | Select-HashTable -Include a,b,c -Exclude b


Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              1
c                              3
```

Answer (score 4):

As the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35783327/1128705) was resulting in a `BadEnumeration` exception for me (but still worked), I modified it to not throw an exception and also made sure that the original `HashTable` is not modified by cloning it first:

```
# Init Hashtable
$items = @{ a1 = 1; a2 = 2; b1 = 3; b2 = 4}

$filtered = $items.Clone()

$items.Keys | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -notmatch "a.*") { 
        $filtered.Remove($_) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On a modern `PowerShell` (`5`+ as far as I remember) you can use `reduce` pattern. For that you need to use this form of `ForEach-Object`:

```
$Hashtable.Keys 
    | ForEach-Object -Begin { 
        $FilteredHashtable = @{} 
    } -Process {
        if ($_ -eq 'Example') {
            $FilteredHashtable[$_] = $Hashtable[$_];
        }
    } -End {
        $FilteredHashtable
    }
```

Yes, this snippet will return `Hashtable`.

Comment: I edited to make it clearer what's going on here, which is that you're providing 3 scripts blocks, which correspond to the `Begin`, `Process`, and `End` blocks that exist in [Advanced Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.3) and cmdlets. The `Process` block is run once per item, and the `Begin` and `End` blocks only run once, before and after (respectively) the items are processed. Nice answer, thanks!